# I am getting permission error to a folder when I try opening it with io.open

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client

I am trying to run this piece of [code](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/analyze-labels) but I am getting a permission error. What solution do you suggest? Can I replace `io.open` with something else:

```
"""Detect labels given a file path."""
video_client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()
features = [videointelligence.Feature.LABEL_DETECTION]

cwd = "E:/.../Google_Video_API/videos/"
with io.open(cwd, "rb") as movie:
    input_content = movie.read()

operation = video_client.annotate_video(
    request={"features": features, "input_content": input_content}
)
print("\nProcessing video for label annotations:")
```

This is the error I get: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:/.../Google_Video_API/videos/'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. `io.open` expects a file not a directory; `cwd` looks to be a directory
2. `cwd = "E:/.../Google_Video_API/videos/"` includes `...`, is that correct?

Comment: This answer is correct. As a note, directories on Linux systems are a special type of file and they can be opened provided the application has the correct permissions to access the directory.